# Asp.Net chart.js 500 internal server error using .asmx web method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, chart.js, ashx

I am trying to draw Multi-series chart in my asp webforms application. I use this tutorial [Link](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/HTML5-Canvas-Multi-Series-Line-Chart-Graph-in-ASPNet.aspx)

and get error. Same problem was happed when I try to draw Pie chart where I use this tutorial [Link1](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Free-HTML5-Canvas-charts-using-Chartjs-in-ASPNet.aspx)

For both time I get the same error. On Page load i get this error:

```
Chart.asmx/GetChart:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

And when I change dropdownlist selection I get this error

```
jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:55550/Chart.asmx/GetChart 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

**EDIT** The same error happens when i publish app.
I have web method Chart.asmx and method in that method is GetChart. Source code of method is:

```
public static List<object> GetChart(string policaID, int zaposlenik)
    {
        List<object> chartData = new List<object>();
        string query = "SELECT DISTINCT DATEPART(YEAR, pocetak) Year FROM Police";
        DataTable dtYears = GetData(query);
        List<int> labels = new List<int>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dtYears.Rows)
        {
            labels.Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["Year"]));
        }
        chartData.Add(labels);
        query = string.Format("SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, p.pocetak) Year,COUNT(DATEPART(YEAR, p.pocetak)) BrojPolica from Police p RIGHT JOIN Zaposlenici z on p.djelatnik = z.zaposleniID " +
        "WHERE p.vrsta_police = " + policaID + " GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, p.pocetak)");
        List<int> series1 = new List<int>();
        DataTable dtPolice = GetData(query);
        foreach (DataRow row in dtPolice.Rows)
        {
            series1.Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["BrojPolica"]));
        }
        chartData.Add(series1);
        query = string.Format("SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, p.pocetak) Year,COUNT(DATEPART(YEAR, p.pocetak)) BrojPolica from Police p RIGHT JOIN Zaposlenici z on p.djelatnik = z.zaposleniID " +
            "WHERE p.djelatnik=" + zaposlenik.ToString() + " GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, p.pocetak)");
        List<int> series2 = new List<int>();
        DataTable dtZaposlenik = GetData(query);
        foreach (DataRow row in dtZaposlenik.Rows)
        {
            series2.Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["BrojPolica"]));
        }
        chartData.Add(series2);

        return chartData;
    }
```

I also have two dropdown lists. One is to change type of insurance policies, and second one is to choose employee. Aspx page looks like this

```
Vrsta Police:
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlVrstaPolice" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                        Djelatnik:
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlZaposlenike" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                        <div id="dvChart">                         
                        </div>
                        <p class="text-center">
```

And Java script code for drawing chart is:

```
$(function () {
            LoadChart();
            $("[id*=ddlVrstaPolice], [id*=ddlZaposlenike]").bind("change", function () {
                LoadChart();
            });
        });
        function LoadChart() {
            var vrsta_police = $("[id*=ddlVrstaPolice]").val();
            var zaposlenik = $("[id*=ddlZaposlenike]").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Chart.asmx/GetChart") %>',
                data: "{policaID: '" + vrsta_police + "', zaposlenik: '" + zaposlenik + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    var labels = r.d[0];
                    var series1 = r.d[1];
                    var series2 = r.d[2];
                    var data = {
                        labels: r.d[0],
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: vrsta_police,
                                fillColor: "rgba(255, 255, 193, 0.2)",
                                strokeColor: "#FCD209",
                                pointColor: "#FF8C00",
                                data: series1
                            },
                            {
                                label: zaposlenik,
                                fillColor: "rgba(217, 237, 247, 0.2)",
                                strokeColor: "#BCE8F1",
                                pointColor: "#0090CB",
                                data: series2
                            }
                        ]
                    };
                    $("#dvChart").html("");
                    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    $("#dvChart")[0].appendChild(canvas);

                    //Fix for IE 8
                    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == "8.0") {
                        G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
                    }
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    ctx.canvas.height = 300;
                    ctx.canvas.width = 500;
                    var lineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
                        bezierCurve: false
                    });
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert('There was an error.');
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Can you wrap in try-catch your GetChart implementation, add breakpoint in catch body and add an Exception with StackTrace to your question?

Comment: Sounds funny maybe but I dont know how to it. Where should I write exception and what type of exception use. I try to google it but didnt find solution

Comment: In the handler for this endpoint `http://localhost:55550/Chart.asmx/GetChart` add try-catch for `Exception `class

Comment: I don't see `[WebMethod]` attribute above GetChart method